# SQL Server : Segregate data into dynamic buckets

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, dense-rank

Please help me with a SQL Server Query that can bucket data dynamically into ranges.

Here is my source data:

```
Value
=======
45

33.5
33.1
33
32.8

25.3
25.2
25.1
25

21.3
21.2
21.1
20.9

12.3
12.2
12.15
12.1
12
11.8
```

Expected output:

```
Value  Rank
=============
45        1
(mean value in this range is 45)

33.5      2
33.1      2
33        2
32.8      2
(mean value is 33.1 - any value in the range (-10%) 29.79 to 36.41 (+10%) should be given a rank of 2)

25.3      3
25.2      3
25.1      3
25        3

21.3      4
21.2      4
21.1      4
20.9      4

12.3      5
12.2      5
12.15     5
12.1      5
12        5
11.8      5
```

DENSE, RANK and NTILE does not seem to give me a ranking like this. The range is dynamic and not known earlier. Any help highly appreciated.

The bucketing rule is:

Each bucket contains a data set with 10% variation from the mean value

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I have added some more info to your post based on a comment further down. Please edit your post further with more sample details - i.e. what is the mean, and an example calculation for a few buckets

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
select val, dense_rank() over (order by cast(val/10 as int) desc) ntile 
from yourtable
```

Use `dense_rank` but specify your buckets in the `order by` clause. (I'm assuming this is how it works for your sample data)

Comment: If `val = 30.5`, then the `rank` would be 2 with your query. But I think, OP needs rank = 3 if `val = 30.5`.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem fully.. 

Val/10 may not work for me as the grouping clause because there could be two clusters between 20 and 30. Is there is way for me cluster values with say 10% variance? I have changed the question to add additional data set

Comment: You can change the bucketing logic in order by. Divide by,  say, 4 and you get a different number of buckets. Can you specify what are your expected buckets/logic in your question rather than making us guess?

Comment: my logic is to identify those clusters in the data and rank it. Our data can vary from few hundreds to a million. A cluster is a data set with 10% variation from the mean value

Comment: I will edit your post and add this vital business rule. Next time please explain in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the value to a number having 2 decimal places.
Then, use a `CASE` expression for doing `FLOOR` or `ROUND` function based on the first number after decimal point.
Then use `DENSE_RANK` function for giving rank based on the rounded value.

**Query**

```
select z.[Value], dense_rank() over(order by z.[val_rounded] desc) as [Rank] from(
    select t.[Value],
    case when substring(t.[Value2], charindex('.', t.[Value2], 1) + 1, 1) > 5 
    then round(t.[Value], 0) else floor(t.[Value]) end as [val_rounded] from(
        select [Value], cast((cast([Value]as decimal(6, 2))) as varchar(50)) as [Value2]
        from [your_table_name]
    )t
)z;
```

### **[`Demo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/612925/sql-server-segregate-data-into-dynamic-buckets)**